# Node.JS Error in FreeBSD

Tags: node.js, freebsd

I develop Node.Js in Ubuntu and deploy it to a server running FreeBSD. When I run npm start, I got this error

```
Error: Shared object "libpthread.so.0" not found, required by "bcrypt_lib.node"
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:440:18)
at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
```

I couldn't find the solution. How to fix it?

Comment: did you install that package (libpthread.so.0)? It's an Ubuntu package

Comment: I copied all node modules from my computer (Ubuntu) to the FreeBSD server, then I installed node and npm. I don't know how to install libpthread.so.0 in FreeBSD

Comment: You could try symlinking `libpthread.so.0` to `libpthread.so`. Take a look at your `/usr/lib` directory - there is a lot of symlinking between library versions.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to get `node.js` on FreeBSD is to install it (and `npm`) as packages.

To install the package, run `pkg install www/node www/npm`. This will install `node`, `npm` and all its prequisites. At the moment this will give you node version 5.10 and npm 3.8.6.